# Using filepath as a hyperlink in HTML

Tags: html, c, file, hyperlink, cgi

I Wonder whether I can use pdf Source[as hyperlink] as a file path in system related to script's running directory.

part of code is.

```
 <a href="../pdfs/sample.pdf">pdf</a>
```

I am generating this HTML using CGI Scripting in C. and my pdfs are located in ../pdfs/sample.pdf related to my running directory of script. And by pdf source means I want to show the pdf sample.pdf upon clicking pdf as in above sample code.

Comment: Also: I don't get the question. Could you please explain what you mean by pdf sopurce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser does not care or know how a resource is generated. You can generate it with C via CGI, you can have the server just hand over a static file. There is no difference as far as the browser is concerned, it made an HTTP request and received an HTTP response.

The rules for resolving a relative URI in an HTML document are the same. The browser compares it to the base URI (which is either specified in `<base>` or is the URI of the document containing the link).

If that resolves to a URI that the server will serve a PDF up for, then it will work.

Since URIs don't always map directly onto file systems, it isn't possible to say if this will work in your situation (as your question only talks about file systems). If this was on one of the servers that I have CGI programmes executing on then it wouldn't work — since I keep them in a cgi-bin that isn't a subdirectory of the webroot, so the pdfs wouldn't be accessible over HTTP at all. Your server may be configured differently.

Comment: Well I am running the script on a Server like you said. So I won't be able to access pdfs present in filesystem? Then how can I configure server for this purpose?

Comment: *So I won't be able to access pdfs?* — That isn't what I said. I said you the PDFs have to have a URI and that the URI you specify in the HTML resolve to match it.

Comment: *Then how can I configure server for this purpose?* — I don't know what server you have, how it is configured now, or what your file system looks like. It shouldn't be hard though, serving up static files is the simplest thing you can do with the vast majority of webservers.

Comment: So if I specify the exact URI of Pdfs in System it should work?

Comment: Of course. It just isn't possible to tell if the URI you specified in the question matched the URI of the PDFs on your server based on the information you provided.